# Placeholder was not found in the current rendering data - JSS sitecore 9 with VueJs

Tags: jss

- In Disconnected mode
- JSS Tech Preview 3
- Sample vue JS

I have a component : data/component-content/**Footer-nav**
With an ID : ID__footer-nav

I can link all my pages to this component perfectly:

```
"PH__footer": [
    {
        "id": "ID__footer-nav"
    }
]
```

Nevertheless, if I create a new placeholder inside this component

`<placeholder name="PH__footer-col" :rendering="rendering" />`

and add data in my Footer-nav/en.json, I have this error in my console.log:

```
#Placeholder 'PH__footer-col' was not found in the current rendering data
{
  "uid": "{3FC3DAE1-AA1D-5D7E-997D-9AB58DFFE0F9}",
  "componentName": "FooterNav",
  "dataSource": "available-in-connected-mode",
  "params": {},
  "fields": {
      #(... I hide them for clarity ...)
  }
}
```

- My data are in my manifest
- If I put my data in routes/en.json (bellow the ID) instead of routes/component-content/Footer-nav/en.json, I have not this problem.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the JSON returned by the disconnected layout service (devtools network tab in the browser)? I just tried this on the latest Vue sample (using YAML routes, but should be equivalent source data) by changing the name of the `main` placeholder to `PH__footer-col` in the route file and the `App.vue` and it worked ok for me.

Comment: Also, check that the placeholder data makes it to the `/sitecore/manifest/sitecore-import.json` file when you run `jss manifest -c` - that can diagnose further whether the issue is in manifest data generation, or the disconnected layout service that pulls data from that manifest.

Comment: I have edited my Question to add more details and I can confirm that ma placeholder data are in my manifest, so I think the issue is from the disconnected layout service.
For information my placeholders are nested like this :

PH__footer > PH__footer-col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a Slack conversation just now, the issue here was that the expectation was that using an ID reference to pull in a shared component content would also pull in child layout.

ID references in a route are shared content references, but do not support child placeholders within the ID-referenced component (i.e. you cannot define `placeholders` on something in `/data/component-content`).

Placeholders *can* be defined on the route item that refers to the shared content item under the ID reference, e.g.:

```
- id: component-shared-id
  placeholders:
    PH__footer-col:
    - id: footer-shared-1
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works for me but of course, I need to create a lot of folders because each link in my footer-nav is a component inside a placeholder, inside a component, inside a placeholder, inside a component...

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error today and in my instance it was due to my adding a new placholder to the layout (code first) and not adding it to the `rootPlaceholders` setting in package.json (AFAIK this is only referenced in the [JSS 11 release notes](https://jss.sitecore.com/release-notes))